# Modify Line in text file by reading line by line

Tags: c#

I have a text file like below:

Input File:

[image]

I want to read this file line by line and blank out first 1-17 character in each line.
then I want to overwrite that line in a same position.
Due to memory issue I can't read all lines like File.ReadAllText(path)

OutPut File:
[image]

I have one option that I read line by line and save that modify line in other file and then move modify data back to original file but I don't want to do that.

Any other way?

Comment: You nailed it in the caption - read the file line by line, modifying it in place. So, besides the screenshots what else have you tried?

Comment: I read the line using stream reader and put it in a string builder and blank out 1-17 position now I need to write that modify line at a position from where I read it without using any other second file.

Comment: Not Duplicate but want to some think like that.

Comment: @MaheshChitroda I am afraid the link log0 provided is pretty much the de facto way of doing what you are after. There might be a better way/library, but I don't know of one. While the solution of creating a new file seems naive, it is definitely very simple/quick to implement. Is there a reason why that is not ideal? Is this file absolutely gigantic?

Comment: This is something that's written in C as homework, I don't see how this could be any different from any other example. If the file is gigantic, writing to it will be slow and it might be better to use a database instead (of a gigantic file)?

Comment: Like, the same way you 'blank out 1-17', use whatever `fseek()` call you're using to seek to that position and write over the old values. I would even skip the blanking out and simply write over the old values in one pass, instead of two (blanking, overwriting blanks)

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279712/replacing-a-line-in-a-file-in-place-c-sharp?lq=1) you'll find something interesting.

Use option #1. Beware of Locale encoding!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile` to load it to memory.
Then do all the required changes and save it back to the disk.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx